# js обновить время в дате

Tags: javascript, дата

у меня есть переменная, которая хранит время в млс
const tillDate = 1685105548411
мне нужно преобразовать эту дату так, чтобы число месяц и год остались теми же, а время обновилось на now, если было 26 мая 2023 15:40 - то получаем 26 мая 2023 15:55. 15:55 - это время когда отработала программа и да ответ должен быть в млс

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tillDate = 1685105548411;
var date = new Date(tillDate);

console.log(tillDate);
console.log(date);

var now = new Date();
var nowHours = now.getHours();
var nowMinutes = now.getMinutes();
var nowSeconds = now.getSeconds();

date.setHours(nowHours);
date.setMinutes(nowMinutes);
date.setSeconds(nowSeconds);

var newTimestamp = date.getTime();

console.log(newTimestamp);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: постарайтесь добавлять более развёрнутые ответы